# После закрытия activity открыть fragment

Tags: android

Здраствуйте , через notification я открываю activity, но не само приложение .
при нажатии на кнопку в activity , activity закрывается .
как после закрытия activity открыть приложения на нужном fragment ?

Comment: Что значит "я открываю activity, но не само приложение"? Активити является частью приложения.

Comment: да но приложение находится в состоянии ondestroy .начинаю timer в timer activity , выходит notification закрываю приложение  нажимаю на notification открывается timer acivity закрываю timer activity и все , а надо чтоб после закрытия activity открылось приложение на нужном фрагменте

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что вам мешает вместо закрытия актвити открыть фрагмент?..

Comment: у меня есть timer activty там находится service timer . я начинаю  timer выводится notification . сейчас я закрыл приложения , но через нажатия на  notification я попадаю на  timer activity . само приложения до сих пор закрыта . при остановления timer активити закрывается  . в итоге у меня закрыта  activity and fragment

Comment: Ну... Передайте что-то через интент запуска из уведомления и, если это что-то в интенте есть в активити, то не запускайте/остановите таймер...